# User Authentication with Bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, bcrypt

I'm attempting to use Bcrypt (3.1.11) and has_secure_password in Rails (5.1.2) for a basic user authentication. It should be quite straightforward, but doesn't seem to be!

I've pretty much copied all the code from the Railscast so the code should be accurate, but the error message is telling me:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#create
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.password: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."password" = ? LIMIT ?
```

Below is the code for `UsersController#create`

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

and the strong params:

```
private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

and the User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_secure_password
 validates_uniqueness_of :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem could be, so any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please show us user model

Comment: This has been added, thanks

Comment: remove `validates_uniqueness_of :email, :password, :password_confirmation`, and try again ?

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but of course validation is there for a reason! Or is this validation something that is included in Bcrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answser (Modify User Model):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_secure_password
 validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

With `has_secure_password` :

> The following validations are added automatically:
>
> - Password must be present on creation
> - Password length should be less than or equal to 72 characters
> - Confirmation of password (using a password_confirmation attribute)
>
> If password confirmation validation is not needed, simply leave out
>   the value for password_confirmation (i.e. don't provide a form field
>   for it). When this attribute has a nil value, the validation will not
>   be triggered.

In fact the password will be crypted, so nobody know it only user self. I can understand the reason why you control email being unique but it's not necessary for password.